# How do I make a flickering engine exhaust animation using only bone animation?

Tags: animation, skeletal-animation

I'm trying to replicate the flickering engine exhaust animation in [this SketchFab model](https://sketchfab.com/models/b9f7850e62a748d1a01ef7fb7c19ad09).  SketchFab doesn't support particle systems, so the animation must be a simple bone animation.

Can someone help me understand how to achieve such an effect?

My best guess is animated opacity, but I don’t know how to replicate it.
My final goal is to use it in a Unity 5 mobile game.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be approximating that using partially transparent objects moving in and out of the engine.

Quick mock-up, slowed down:

[image: proposed structure for the animation]

The images attached to the moving bones just look like this:

[image: long part of the fire] [image: short part of the fire]